# How to create 2 wave containers (top and bottom) in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am learning flutter by examples and looking at some answered questions on here. I would like to achieve the below screen. I am learning from the answer to this question here [How to create stacked wave containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68300913/how-to-create-stacked-wave-containers)
What do I need to do to make the screen look like shown below? [image: top and bottom container are flips of the other]

Comment: Why don't you just draw this background on canvas?
You could make a drawer, then with expirience it will be much easier to move on to custom shape clipper, if it is really needed.
From your question it is not clear, what is the goal you are trying to achieve? if it is custom background you could just insert an image, else you can draw it on canvas, previously put it into bottom stack layer, if it is a custom behavior, start with canvas functions will be helpful anyway, as you will have an idea how paths work.

Comment: Just looking for a starting point. I will consider your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `CustomPainter` will draw the first container on the image. You can change the x, y coordinates and get a second container.

```
class WavePainter extends CustomPainter {
  WavePainter({
    required this.radius,
  });

  final double radius;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..shader = const LinearGradient(colors: [
        Colors.lightGreenAccent,
        Colors.green,
      ]).createShader(Offset.zero & size);
    
    final path = Path()
      ..moveTo(0, 0)
      ..lineTo(0, size.height - 2 * radius)
      ..arcToPoint(
        Offset(radius, size.height - radius),
        radius: Radius.circular(radius),
        clockwise: false,
      )
      ..lineTo(size.width - radius, size.height - radius)
      ..arcToPoint(
        Offset(size.width, size.height),
        radius: Radius.circular(radius),
      )
      ..lineTo(size.width, 0)
      ..lineTo(0, 0)
      ..close();

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Use it inside widget like this:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: WavePainter(radius: 40),
          size: Size(200, 200),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```